# Scala equality with type checking?

Tags: scala, operators, equality

Is there a uniform method to perform equality with type checking?
Unfortunately

```
val objectA:String = "test"
val objectB:Int = 2
objectA == objectB
```

the equality operator == doesn't complain if objectB is a Int while objectA is a String.
I would need an operator like === that perform type checking as well (and I hope it is uniform to all scala obj). Does such operator exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to look at [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)'s [===](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/Identity.scala.html#48590) for type-safe equals - it's implemented as type class there.

You can also watch talk by [Heiko Seeberger](https://twitter.com/#!/hseeberger), where he describes how it's implemented:

http://days2011.scala-lang.org/node/138/275

You can also find some examples here:

http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleEqual.scala.html#24187

(in the examples they are using `≟` method, but it's simply alias for `===`)

Comment: Is there a way to make compiler warn about this?

Answer (score 8):

Scalaz provides such an operator.

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> 4 === "Scala"
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("Scala")
 required: Int
              4 === "Scala"
                    ^

scala> 4 === 4
res7: Boolean = true

scala> 4 === 5
res8: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 2):

This is also provided by the [ScalaUtils](http://www.scalautils.org/user_guide/ConstrainedEquality) library:

```
import org.scalautils.TypeCheckedTripleEquals._

scala> "Scala" == Some("Scala")
res1: Boolean = false

scala> "Scala" === Some("Scala")
<console>:11: error: types String and Some[String] do not adhere to the type
  constraint selected for the === and !== operators; the missing implicit 
  parameter is of type org.scalautils.Constraint[String,Some[String]]
              "Scala" === Some("Scala")
                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

scala dotty(aka scala 3) has a feature called [Multiversal Equality](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/multiversal-equality.html) which allows type safe equality.

Below is the dotty REPL example;

```
scala> val data1 = "string" 
val data1: String = "string"

scala> val data2 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4) 
val data2: Array[Int] = [I@86733

scala> val comparisonBool = data1 == data2 
1 |val comparisonBool = data1 == data2
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |    Values of types String and Array[Int] cannot be compared with == or !=
```

Dotty is a next generation compiler for Scala - http://dotty.epfl.ch/#getting-started

[Note:](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/04/19/scala-3.html#when-will-it-come-out)

> When will scala 3 come out?
>
> The intent is to publish the final Scala 3.0
> soon after Scala 2.14. At the current release schedule (which might
> still change), that means early 2020.