# Spark specify multiple logical condition in where clause of spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While defining the multiple logical/relational condition in spark scala dataframe getting the error as mentioned below. But same thing is working fine in scala

Python code:

```
df2=df1.where(((col('a')==col('b')) & (abs(col('c')) <= 1))
 | ((col('a')==col('fin')) & ((col('b') <= 3) & (col('c') > 1)) & (col('d') <= 500))
 | ((col('a')==col('b')) & ((col('c') <= 15) & (col('c') > 3)) & (col('d') <= 200))
 | ((col('a')==col('b')) & ((col('c') <= 30) & (col('c') > 15)) & (col('c') <= 100)))
```

Tried for scala equivalent:

```
val df_aqua_xentry_dtb_match=df_aqua_xentry.where((col("a") eq col("b")) &  (abs(col("c") ) <= 1))
```

```
 notebook:2: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Boolean
```

```
val df_aqua_xentry_dtb_match=df_aqua_xentry.where((col("a") eq col("b")) &  (abs(col("c") ) <= 1))
```

How to define multiple logical condition in spark dataframe using `scala`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below solution.

```
df.where("StudentId == 1").explain(true)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('StudentId = 1)
+- Project [_1#3 AS StudentId#7, _2#4 AS SubjectName#8, _3#5 AS Marks#9]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#3, _2#4, _3#5]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
StudentId: int, SubjectName: string, Marks: int
Filter (StudentId#7 = 1)
+- Project [_1#3 AS StudentId#7, _2#4 AS SubjectName#8, _3#5 AS Marks#9]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#3, _2#4, _3#5]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [StudentId#7, SubjectName#8, Marks#9]
```

Here we used where clause, internally optimizer converted to filter opetration eventhough where clause in code level.

So we can apply filter function on rows of data frame like below

```
df.filter(row => row.getString(1) == "A" && row.getInt(0) == 1).show()

Here 0 and 1 are columns of data frames. In my case schema is (StudentId(Int), SubjectName(string), Marks(Int))
```

Answer (score 0):

`eq` returns a `Boolean`, `<=` returns a `Column`. They are incompatible.

You probably want this :

```
df.where((col("a") === col("b")) && (abs(col("c") ) <= 1))
```

`===` is used for equality between columns and returns a `Column`, and there we can use `&&` to do multiple conditions in the same where.

Answer (score 0):

With Spark you should use

- **`===`** instead of `==` or `eq` (see [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490236/difference-between-and-in-scala-spark))
- **`&&`** instead of `&` (`&&` is logical AND, `&` is binary AND)

```scala
val df_aqua_xentry_dtb_match = df_aqua_xentry.where((col("a") === col("b")) &&  (abs(col("c") ) <= 1))
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your recommendation. Its working now.
val df2=df1.where(((col("a") ===col("b")) &&  (abs(col("c") ) <= 1)) || 
                                                   ((col("a")===col("b")) && ((col("c") <= 3) && (col("c") > 1)) && (col("d") <= 500)) || ((col("a")===col("b")) && ((col("c") <= 15) && (col("c") > 3)) && (col("d") <= 200)) || ((col("a")===col("b")) && ((col("c") <= 30) && (col("c") > 30)) && (col("d") <= 200)))

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your Scala version of code.

1. "eq" is basically to compare two strings in Scala (desugars to == in Java) so 
   when you try to compare two Columns using "eq", it returns a boolean 
   instead of Column type. Here you can use "===" operator for Column comparison.

String comparison

```
    scala> "praveen" eq "praveen"
    res54: Boolean = true 

    scala> "praveen" eq "nag"
    res55: Boolean = false   

    scala> lit(1) eq lit(2)
    res56: Boolean = false  

    scala> lit(1) eq lit(1)
    res57: Boolean = false
```

Column  comparison

```
    scala> lit(1) === lit(2)
    res58: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (1 = 2)

    scala> lit(1) === lit(1)
    19/08/02 14:00:40 WARN Column: Constructing trivially true equals predicate, '1 = 1'. Perhaps you need to use aliases.
    res59: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (1 = 1)
```

2. You are using a "betwise AND" operator instead of "and"/"&&" operator for Column type. This is reason you were getting the above error (as it was expecting a boolean instead Column).

   ```
     scala> df.show
     +---+---+
     | id|id1|
     +---+---+
     |  1|  2|
     +---+---+

     scala> df.where((col("id") === col("id1")) && (abs(col("id")) > 2)).show
     +---+---+
     | id|id1|
     +---+---+
     +---+---+

     scala> df.where((col("id") === col("id1")) and (abs(col("id")) > 2)).show
     +---+---+
     | id|id1|
     +---+---+
     +---+---+
   ```

Hope this helps !